# python text parsing to get filtered output

Tags: python, parsing

My goal is to search file.txt to find a identifying string and then output the following words between the quotation marks.

So the identifier would be data-default-alt= and the name of the item is "Ford Truck" in quotes. I would like to output the name of the item and the price so that i can open it in excel.

```
data-default-alt="Ford Truck">       </h3>     </a>           </div>     <div class="tileInfo">                <div class="swatchesBox--empty"></div>                                                     <div class="promo-msg-text">           <span class="calloutMsg-promo-msg-text"></span>         </div>                              <div class="pricecontainer" data-pricetype="Stand Alone">               <p id="price_206019013" class="price price-label ">                  $1,000.00               </p>
```

Desired Output would be

Ford Truck  1000.00

I am not sure how to go about this task.

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well please construct more robust regular expressions for matching your cost and/or brand, here is some code to get you started.

```
str = '<data-default-alt="Ford Truck"></h3></a></div><div class="tileInfo"><div class="swatchesBox--empty"></div><div class="promo-msg-text"> <span class="calloutMsg-promo-msg-text"></span> </div><div class="pricecontainer" data-pricetype="Stand Alone"><p id="price_206019013" class="price price-label ">$1,000.00</p>'

import re

brand=re.search('<data-default-alt=\"(.*?)">',str)
cost=re.search('\$(\d+,?\d*\.\d+)</p>',str)
if brand:
        print brand.group(1)
if cost:
        print cost.group(1)
```

Comment: Thanks this gave me output of Ford Truck 1,000.00. How do i read from a text file?

Comment: there will be multiples of these in each file also how do i get all of them?

Comment: I am EST Time zone

Comment: Getting this error now. brand=re.search('<data-default-alt=\"(.*?)">',str) File "C:\Users\turtle02\Anaconda2\lib\re.py", line 146, in search return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string) TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: all code   with open("file.txt") as str:
    st = str.read()
    
    import re    

    brand=re.search('<data-default-alt=\"(.*?)">',str)
    cost=re.search('\$(\d+,?\d*\.\d+)</p>',str)
if brand:
        print brand.group(1)
if cost:
        print cost.group(1)

Comment: Using this code I get the list of all names but no prices     with open("file.txt") as str:
    st = str.read()
    
import re
brand=re.findall('data-default-title=\"(.*?)" ',st)

cost=re.search('\$(\d+,?\d*\.\d+)</p>',st)

print '\n'.join(brand)
print '\n'.join(cost)
print cost

Answer (score 0):

Use the default string methods to find the substring index. For example, `"abcdef".find("bc")` would return 1, which is the index of the first letter of the substring. To parse your string, you could look for tags and then extract the needed text using string slicing.
So this is an example of solving your problem, considering that the parsed string is being stored in a `st` variable:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    st = f.read() # that's to get the file contents
name_start = st.find('data-default-alt="') + len('data-default-alt="') # found the first letter's index and added the substring's length to it to skip to the part of the actual data
name_end = st[name_start:].find('"') # found the closing quote
name = st[name_start:name_start + name_end] # sliced the string to get what we wanted

price_start = st.find('class="price price-label ">') + len('class="price price-label ">')
price_end = st[price_start:].find('</p>')
price = st[price_start:price_start + price_end].strip().rstrip()
```

The results are in `name` and `price` variables. If you wanna work with the price as a number and don't want the dollar sign, add it to the strip arguments (`.strip("$ ")`, read more on that method in Python docs). You can remove the comma by calling a `replace(",", "")` on the price string and after all, convert the string to a float using `float(price)`
Notes: it may just be the way you put the parsed string in, but I've added `strip()` and `rstrip()` methods to get rid of whitespaces on each end of the price string.

Comment: I seem to have messed up something i get this output {{= $item.parent.data.itemAttributes.title}}
$2.84 there will be multiples of these in each file also how do i get all of them?

Comment: @turtle02 If you will have multiple of those, you might be better off using regular expressions. If you're having trouble reading from a file, take a look at the first two lines of my code, they do just that.

Comment: Getting this error now.   brand=re.search('<data-default-alt=\"(.*?)">',str)
  File "C:\Users\turtle02\Anaconda2\lib\re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @turtle02 Please, provide the `str` variable contents by printing it right before that error-causing line

Comment: <li class="tile standard atc-enabled"><div class="tileImage"><a href="http://www.example.com/p/ford-truck/-/A-14773925#prodSlot=_1_1" title="ford-truck" id="prodTitle-medium-1-1" class="productClick" name="prodImageTitle_206019013" data-title="ford-truck" data-default-title="ford-truck" data-default-href="/p/ford-truck/-/A-14773925#prodSlot=_1_1">       <h3>         <img style="visibility: visible;" text"></span>         </div><div class="pricecontainer" data-pricetype="Stand Alone">   <p id="price_206019013" class="price price-label ">     $1000.00</p><p class="regularprice-label">

Comment: Are you sure that this is a string?

Comment: This is the data in the file i am trying to use, it is a html page saved as txt. that I upload to my website.

Comment: I'm unable to recreate this issue. Could you post your code on pastebin.com as well as the txt file with the contents?

Comment: Yes give me just a min

Comment: I see what's wrong. The variable str is a file object, you read the contents of it into the st variable. But in your re.search, you try to search a file object for your regex instead of searching a string. Basically just change the second argument in those search statements from str to st, that should fix everything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107775/discussion-between-leva7-and-turtle02).